# Bend a mesh along spline

Tags: math, 3d, mesh

I am trying to bend a mesh along a spline curve and currently out of ideas … at first I thought I just add spline point vectors to mesh's vertices , but I am looking for more optimized version of it …

so guys …

How can I bend a mesh along a spline, so that mesh, with some forward axis vector follows the spline and bends according to it and also repeat along the spline …

[image]

???

Comment: Adding vectors to mesh's vertices is `O(V*Q)` or something (`V` is the number of vertices, `Q` is the complexity of quering a point on the spline), what do you mean by more optimized version?

Comment: I am unaware of this algorithm at that moment, can elaborate with some code.

Comment: Simplified pseudocode: `for (auto& v: mesh.vertices()) v+=spline.get(v.x);`

Comment: No no , I think adding mesh's vertices to spline vertices may not give the correct result ...  I  think it is other way around...

Comment: Please post a figure explaining what you want.

Comment: By the way, do you know what an *offset curve* is ?

Comment: it is not just always a cylinder ... it can be a extruded mesh like a bridge in real life. Also dont want to generate procedural geometry using spline points, an external mesh needs to be bent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are many ways to do what you want. Some years ago I worked out an approach using [Conformal Geometric Algebra](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mauricio-Lopez-Belon-2/publication/261022353_Applications_of_Conformal_Geometric_Algebra_in_Mesh_Deformation/links/5fa99621299bf10f73303953/Applications-of-Conformal-Geometric-Algebra-in-Mesh-Deformation.pdf). Of course you can do it using conventional 3D math as its described in [Instant Mesh Deformation](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/%7Eoliveira/pubs_files/Blanco_Oliveira_I3D_2008_final.pdf) and [Deformation styles for spline-based skeletal animation](http://svenforstmann.com/pdf/2007.SCA.Paper.pdf) papers.

A simple method is as follows:

Your spline function is a function S(t): R -> R^3, it takes a scalar between [0:1] and give you points in R^3.

1. Project each mesh vertex on the spline curve. The projection is orthogonal in the sense that it follows the direction of a normal vector to the curve. So your mesh vertex v_i is projected to a point v'_i in the spline where S(t_i) = v'_i. Form a vector p_i = v_i - v'_i (which is normal to the curve) so each mesh vertex can be expressed as:

   v_i = S(t_i) + p_i
2. Compute an orthogonal coordinate system at "each point" of the spline. That coordinate system is known as [Frenet-Serret frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas). The first vector to determine is the tangent to the curve. It is uniquely defined as the derivative of S(t) so tangent  T = S(t)/dt. The other two vectors, the normal N and binormal B, can be computed in different ways, check the above reference papers for that.
3. Express the vector p_i (from step 1) in terms of the Frenet-Serret frame at point S(t_i). Such that the vector p_i is a linear combination of T, N and B. Create a matrix A with columns T, N and B. You need to find x_i such that:

   A x_i = p_i

   That can be solved by inverting the matrix A (actually taking the transpose should suffice). So each mesh vertex can be computed as:

   v_i = S(t_i) + A x_i

   You can store the pair (t_i, x_i) instead of v_i (you don't need to store v_i anymore since you can compute it from t_i and x_i).
4. To deform the mesh deformation the spline control points must be translated, then you need to recompute the Frenet-Serret frame of each spline point (taking the derivative of the S(t) to compute T and updating the N and B as suggested in above reference papers). Once you have the updated T, N and B, you can define the matrix A and then compute the mesh vertex positions using formula from step 3.

Results can be seen in pictures of the above mentioned papers.